# How to specify collation on Documents (Class in MongoEngine)?

Tags: mongodb, mongoengine, flask-mongoengine

I have the following class:

```
class Subject(me.Document):
    name = me.StringField(unique=True)
    topic = me.StringField(required=True, choices=('Language', 'Other'))
    isCompulsory = me.BooleanField(required=True, default=False)

    meta = {
        'collation': {
            'locale': 'en',
            'caseLevel': False
        }
    }
```

The MongoEngine Docs do not provide any example.

I have two requirements:

1. Make `choices` to be case-insensitive.
2. I am able to insert values like `physics`, `Physics` in `name` field. Make DB treat them as *same*.

NB: I have dropped Collection (using MongoDB Compass) before trying this.

Info:

- MongoDB Version : `4.0.3`
- flask-mongoengine version : `0.9.5`
- mongoengine version : `0.20.0`

Comment: Were you able to figure out a solution?

Comment: @subtleseeker I checked my project and found this ```meta = {
        'indexes': [
            {
                'fields': ['name'],
                'collation': {'locale': 'en', 'strength': 1}
            },
            {
                'fields': ['topic'],
                'collation': {'locale': 'en', 'strength': 1}
            }
        ]
    }``` I hope this works or alternatively, just store small caps always.